# Dynamic google services configuration

Tags: android, firebase, configuration, google-play-services

I have an Android app handling notifications through IBM Bluemix. I created a google-services.json file, added it to the project. It works like a charm.

But now, I want to deploy a generic version of the app to the store. That application will serve different customers, where each customer has to create his own Firebase project and Bluemix account. When initializing, the application should read the necessary ids/secrets from a server instead of getting the values embedded statically in the app.

I saw that the google-services.json file is a convenient way to generate resources in values.xml, but I didn't find how to have these values set dynamically at runtime. Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem but there's no answer. Have you got any solution ?